# How to copy to the clipboard the current path?

Tags: linux, bash, pwd

How can I copy the current path in the bash terminal, using just one command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Needs `xsel` installed:

```
pwd | xsel -i
```

(if you don't want the trailing newline, use `printf %s "$(pwd)" | xsel -i` (mostly correct) `pwd | head -c -1 | xsel -i` (perfectly correct))

---

Update August 2014: The `xsel` program is broken: See my [bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=758599).

Probably you can get along with `xclip` as well.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure I understand the version that pipes through `head`, though. Why pass only the first byte to `xsel`?

Comment: this means "pass everything but the last byte" (which we know is the added newline)

Comment: Oh, right. I was reading that as `head -c 1 -1`.

Comment: Unable to locate package xsel !..any other suggestion !

Comment: @Shubh: `xclip` can be used instead. Actually, `xsel` is quite buggy: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=758599

Answer (score 3):

```
pwd | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
```

Try this... Best I can come up with on my phone.

Comment: doesn't work.............

Comment: `pbcopy` is specific to Mac OS X; it is not available in Linux.

Comment: Woops! Sorry for overlooking that.